# Android video view black screen

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I setup the video view with video. I have three testing devices. I used the first one can play the video normally. But I used another two devices that cannot play the video just show a black screen.
I tried to use another video that can be played on all devices. So is the video problem or other problem.

I just added the `OnInfoListener` and logged the what variable. The value is 10951 that is `MEDIA_INFO_UNSUPPORTED_VIDEO`. So anyone know. what is the meaning of the MEDIA_INFO_UNSUPPORTED_VIDEO.

**Update:**
I found the reason why cannot be played. Because the video codecs is not supported on all android device. My video is used H.264. But Samsung and Nokia cannot support it.  So anyone know which codecs can support on all devices or any way can make me play the video normally.

More detail for the device:
cannot play video: Samsung Galaxy A20s os 10, Nokia C2 os 9
can play video: Redmi Note 4 os 6.0.1

Answer (score 2):

MEDIA_INFO_UNSUPPORTED_VIDEO is shown when the video resolution exceeds the maximum resolution of the codec supported by the chipset.

For H.264,

- Chipset in A20s is [Qualcomm Snapdragon 450](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon-450-mobile-platform) which supports till 1080p.
- Chipset in Redmi Note 4 is [Qualcomm Snapdragon 625](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon-625-mobile-platform) which supports till 4k.
- Chipset in Nokia C2 is [Unisoc 28nm](https://www.notebookcheck.net/UNISOC-SC9863A-SoC-Benchmarks-and-Specs.426937.0.html) which supports till 1080p.

The problem mentioned occurs due to codec limitation and has nothing to do with OS version and player used.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with `VideoView`, but after converting the video, it worked. Try this site and see if it works for you: https://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4 (you don't need to apply any video settings, just upload and hit `Start conversion`)

Anyway I've switched on `ExoPlayer`

Comment: I tried to convert many codecs but also not work

Comment: I used `SimpleExoPlayer` with my video. But still not work